# Импорт данных из Excel в asp.net (textBox)

Tags: asp.net

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста. Не могу осуществить перенос данных из Excel-таблицы в textBox (asp.net).......Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В чем проблема? Вытащить из екселя или засунуть адскую таблицу в маленький текстбокс?

Comment: Проблема вытащить данные из excel и перенести значение каждой ячейки в отдельный textbox.

Comment: А как же погуглить? например вот - http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

Comment: видимо плохо гуглила....спасибо большое за помощь! надеюсь, смогу разобраться, т.к. в этом деле новичок...